# Using successive cin >> input loops

Tags: c++

I have to loops to gather input, the first gathers input into a vector of doubles...

```
double input; 
while (cin >> input)
{
    list.push_back(input);  
}
```

and the second gathers input into a vector of ints...

```
int input; 
while (cin >> input)
{
    list.push_back(input);  
}
```

The second loop keeps auto-exiting and so I added the following two lines...

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');  // I've also tried cin.ignore()
```

However this has occurred in my output being discarded in the second loop. How can I get both of these to work the way they need to?

Comment: how are you escaping either loop?

Comment: not sure if it is good practice, but I have them type exit, so input would be 5.6 7.3 9.4 exit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first loop reads until the stream goes bad because there isn't any `double` to read from. When the stream has gone bad it won't become good again unless you do something, e.g., using `std::cin.clear()` to clear the state flags.

Of course, just clearing the state flags won't make much of a difference because it would have read all viable numbers: the format of valid `double`s is a superset of the format of valid `int`s (well, OK, unless they are using base 16). That is, you'll need some sort of separator, probably a non-space, non-digit character. Your use of `ignore()` should skip over a separator and up to the next newline (although the magic value isn't `INT_MAX` but `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`).

It is unclear what you are trying to input but if you use something like

```
1 2 3 exit 4 5 6
```

the first three values would be read as `double` and everything else would be ignored. That is, you may want to be ignore characters a bit more careful, e.g., clear the input and keep trying to read an `int` and `clear()` and `ignore()` until this is successful:

```
// skip separator:
std::cin.clear();
int input;
while (!(std::cin >> input)) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(); // ignore the next character only
}
do {
    list.push_back(input);
} while (std::cin >> input);
```